After replacing the 6.1.0 kernel for Ubuntu 20.04, the system cannot be started and the message "out of memory" appears
After I replaced the 6.1.0 kernel for Ubuntu 20.04, the system could not be started and prompted out of memory. The original 5.17.0 kernel could be started, but I saw that the 5.17.0 kernel was larger than the 6.1.0-rt5, and it could start normally. Why did the smaller kernel prompt that there was insufficient memory?
dobot@dobot-IB-ITLU-TW01B:~$ ls -ltr /boot/
total 700128
drwx------ 3 root root      4096 1月   1  1970 efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184884 8月  18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    184380 8月  18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    182704 8月  18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw------- 1 root root   6223039 2月  22  2023 System.map-5.15.0-67-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    262250 2月  22  2023 config-5.15.0-67-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11458952 3月  16  2023 vmlinuz-5.15.0-67-generic
-rw------- 1 root root   6255721 7月  11 22:28 System.map-5.15.0-117-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    262374 7月  11 22:28 config-5.15.0-117-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  11560168 7月  11 23:08 vmlinuz-5.15.0-117-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  73887771 8月  17 18:08 initrd.img-5.15.0-67-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  86341511 8月  17 18:08 initrd.img-5.15.0-117-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7057600 8月  17 18:45 vmlinuz-6.1.0-rt5.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3396437 8月  17 18:45 System.map-6.1.0-rt5.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    192874 8月  17 18:45 config-6.1.0-rt5.old
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        20 8月  17 18:46 initrd.img -> initrd.img-6.1.0-rt5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7052896 8月  17 18:55 vmlinuz-6.1.0-rt5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        21 8月  17 18:55 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.1.0-rt5.old
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 8月  17 18:55 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.1.0-rt5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3396437 8月  17 18:55 System.map-6.1.0-rt5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    192874 8月  17 18:55 config-6.1.0-rt5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 498754216 8月  17 18:56 initrd.img-6.1.0-rt5
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root      4096 8月  18 12:38 grub
dobot@dobot-IB-ITLU-TW01B:~$ ls  kernel/
linux-6.1  linux-6.1.tar.gz  patch-6.1-rc7-rt5.patch


Replacing the Canonical -provided kernel with one that you have either built yourself or picked up from another source is prone to trigger problems of this type. Unless you have a very specific reason to attempt this, you're better off sticking to what you can install with e.g. apt or synaptic.

I solved my problem by executing sudo sed -i 's/^MODULES=.*/MODULES=dep/' /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf. After the modification, the generated initrd.img-6.10-rt5 became smaller.
